# Blob to Base64 in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64, ionic3, blob

I have successfully converted my base64 (DATA_URI) image into blob but not able to revert it back.

My base64 to blob code look like below for more info look this [link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/322/how-to-convert-a-base64-image-into-a-image-file-and-upload-it-with-an-asynchronous-form-using-jquery).

```
b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

I am trying to convert my blob to base64 I get an error as

> ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

here is my response for getting back my blob image res [image: link]

I am invoking success callback but not able to under stand this

here is the code where I try to convert blob to base64

```
if(window.FileReader) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
          reader.onloadend = () => {
              var base64data = reader.result;                
              console.log(base64data);
          }
        }
```

While debugging i am not able to see `reader.onloadend` it is null and i am not able to invoke it.

Any help??

Comment: How do you construct the `blob` that you're passing to `reader.readAsDataURL()`?

Comment: If all you have at hand is the string `"1524751188817_blob"`, I'm not sure you can get a `Blob` out of it. The function `b64toBlob` that you're using is expecting the first parameter to be a base64-encoded string.

Comment: @haim770 actully that was wrong in which i have mentioned as blob as array of string actual result show the file something like this `ØÿàJFIFHHÿáXExifMM*‡i&  À Ðÿí8Photoshop 3.08BIM8BIM%ÔŒÙ²é€ ˜ìøB~ÿÀÐÀ"ÿÄ 
ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br,....`

Comment: im getting my Api response as _body is giving me string of blob/file someting like streemed data

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to define `onloadend` before you start reading the data.  It is likely completing the read and firing the null function before you've assigned it. Or more precisely at the moment you call `readAsDataURL`, `onloadend` is `null`.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = () => {
  var base64data = reader.result;                
      console.log(base64data);
}

reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Comment: can you elaborate your answer i am new to dealing with file

Comment: still same issue